# Strange EventLog Behaviour on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, event-handling, windows-server-2008, event-log

I'm using some very simple C# code to monitor the security event log of a domain controller 'live', so that I can capture account lockout events as they happen.

I have code that worked on 2003, but now I've moved it to 2008 R2 (and changed code to match the 4740 event id instead of the older 644 event id) I see all the events getting logged for a few minutes after service start, **but then I get a spate of 'old' messages and then all 0 event ids, spamming forever.** To be definitive, these are firing an entry written event but are all ID=0 entries - this is really bizarre.

I suspect, but haven't tested, that making a new `EventLog("security")` object will correct this issue, but I don't want to be doing this every 2 minutes, and I don't understand why the old events are fired - does anyone have any idea what could be going on?

Below are sample output when the error occurs - happy logs at the top, followed by old logs, followed by 0 logs - in the exact order it happens on my DC. Following that is some code samples:

```
Event received: 5145, Time Gen = 16/04/2013 08:17:27, Time Written = 16/04/2013 08:17:27
[20 more like this edited out (differing event ids)]
Event received: 5145, Time Gen = 16/04/2013 08:00:47, Time Written = 16/04/2013 08:00:47
Event received: 5145, Time Gen = 16/04/2013 08:00:47, Time Written = 16/04/2013 08:00:47
[20 more like this edited out]
Event received: 0, Time Gen = 01/01/1970 00:00:00, Time Written = 01/01/1970 00:00:00
[**infinite** more like this edited out]
```

The code is very simple:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a new security log listener, and enable event firing for that log
/// </summary>
protected void InitialiseSecurityEventLog()
{
    if (securityLog != null)
    {
        securityLog.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
    }

    // Create a security event log listener and put into action
    securityLog = new EventLog("security");
    securityLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(securityLog_EntryWritten);
    securityLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

and to process:

```
/// <summary>
/// Process log events
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void securityLog_EntryWritten(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
{
    // Queue event for processing
    securityEventLogQueue.Add(e.Entry);
}
```

I have a separate thread retrieving entries from the queue (which is a Blocking/ConcurrentQueue) and outputting them to file, which is where the output from above originates from

Thanks for reading! Any and all help appreciated